# Is their any size limit to AngularJS $cacheFactory?

Tags: angularjs, cachefactory

Should I be considering flushing the cache from time to time? Or I can cache all my API responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** **Should I be considering flushing the cache from time to time?**

No. Because $cacheFactory will destroy all the data once the session has been closed. Or if you want to flush manually then you can use destroy method.
**destroy()** - Removes references to this cache from $cacheFactory.

**removeAll()** - Removes all cached values.

**2. I can cache all my API responses?**

This is possible in two ways as follows.

1. $localStorage - If your goal is to store client-side and persistent data.
2. $cacheFactory - Data exist only for current session.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source the cache is simply an object. You provide a key and value and it add a property to that object by your key assigning it the value.

This can be seen [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/cacheFactory.js#L87)

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) state that you can provide an options object to the `$cacheFactory` call specifying a capacity parameter turning it into a LRU cache. Meaning if the capacity is met the last recently used cache is removed.

If you do not provide a capacity then `Number.MAX_VALUE` is used, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/cacheFactory.js#L97).

So in summary yes. It either user imposed when creating the cache or according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) the largest number available to JavaScript.

> The MAX_VALUE property has a value of approximately 1.79E+308.